# What does the form field »Enter Auth username« during the boot proccess mean?

Tags: boot, 15.04

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04 my system shows a strange behaviour  booting: Shortly after the Ubuntu boot splash a form element shows up requiring me to enter an »Auth username«.
The boot process stucks, until I would hit enter. What is that, where does it come from, how can I get rid of it?

That's how in looks like:

```
+------------------------------------------+
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                 Ubuntu°                  |
|                 ....                     |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|           Enter Auth Username            |
|           +------------------+           |
|           |                  |           |
|           +------------------+           |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
+------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Most likely it's from openvpn. Did you define recently any openvpn connection (either directly or using network manager)?

Comment: check your vpn config file. if openvpn: "./build-key-server SERVERNAME" should ask for user and password.

Comment: Same problem, and I have an OpenVPN conf. I tried removing the "Shared by all users" on all connections and still no luck...

Comment: @eloy Thank you for the hint, you where right, that it was caused by `openvpn`. I posted a solution as answer hoping it may help others.

Comment: @DReispt I posted a solution to the problem.

Comment: As a heads up, as of Ubuntu 16.04 this manifests itself as systemd not being able to boot up, and no virtual terminals are created. To boot up and fix the issue edit the boot line in grub and remove "quiet" and "splash".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was caused by some configurations file in `/etc/openvpn`. I don't know why the problem came only up after an upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04 as those files had been a long time before there.
But actually, if you don't run an openvpn server or have some important openvpn configurations you can easily delete all those files with:

```
sudo rm -R /etc/openvpn/*
```

If you want to do a backup first, consider running something like this:

```
sudo tar -czf /etc/openvpn/
```

Comment: That is not really an option if you need to use openvpn to connect to a company network

Answer (score 22):

I encountered this same issue and managed to resolve it. I first opened the OpenVPN init script with:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/openvpn
```

And uncommented the line:

```
AUTOSTART="none"
```

This should stop all OpenVPN connections on startup and thus resolves the issue without actually removing OpenVPN.

Answer (score 1):

I got the prompt at boot time:

```
> Enter Auth UserName:
```

I figured out after some time that it is the openvpn server/service starting up (if you try to stop and start the openvpn.service in systemctl, you will get prompted for a password).
So, if you only need the client to connect from this current machine to another server, you can disable the service like so (Debian 9, Ubuntu 18.04):

```
# systemctl disable openvpn.service
```

Answer (score 0):

I had OpenVPN autostart working without the Auth Username prompt until I switched which VPN I was connecting to at boot.  When I switched I forgot to modify the `auth-user-pass` directive in the new .conf file to point to the username and password file.

I have the username and password stored in `/etc/openvpn/vpn.auth` owned by root with permissions 600 like so:

```
plaintext-username
plaintext-password
```

In the .ovpn file I downloaded from my VPN provider the auth-user-pass directive looked like this:

```
...
auth-user-pass
...
```

I changed it to look like this and it fixed it:

```
...
auth-user-pass "/etc/openvpn/vpn.auth"
...
```

Now it auto starts at boot without the prompt.

Remember to rename the .ovpn file to .conf as that's what the OpenVPN initscript is looking for at boot per the [docs](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/configuring-openvpn-to-run-automatically-on-system-startup/).