# Ubuntu is asking for authentication when booting and before login

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, login, password, authentication

Ubuntu is asking for user and password authentication before user's login. It asks when the Acer logo and Ubuntu logo still appear. After inputing a random username and password, it will bring me to the user login.

It wasn't like that before and the last thing that I remember was that I did something related to ssh. I already removed it, but it doesn't work. As you can see from the picture, it's asking me twice before I could see my desktop.

[image: authentication screen 1]

[image: authentication screen 2]

[image: authentication screen 3]

Comment: Did you happen to have installed OpenVPN on your system at any point?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the form field »Enter Auth username« during the boot proccess mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627842/what-does-the-form-field-enter-auth-username-during-the-boot-proccess-mean)