# Ubuntu 23.10 - a new password page during boot

Tags: boot, login, password

**Ubuntu 23.10, PC, Mate Desktop**

23.10 has been working fine and I wanted to restore my VPN wiped out during the last update/upgrade and worked with the vendor to restore operation. That involved many commands run in Terminal.

After rebooting the final time during that process, I found that Ubuntu would boot to a new password page. I'd enter my password correctly, it would loop right back to that page, I'd enter it again and then it would proceed like normal to the regular password page. Enter that and it would open on the desktop.

I found if I walked away without entering those first two passwords, it would auto proceed to the regular password page. Enter the password, and it goes to the desktop.

Anyone know if it was a command during the 'fix' of the VPN that might have caused this? I don't recall any command related to a KEY or password. Or could it be something else? Or better yet, how to eliminate the redundancy? Booting is already too slow.

[image: New password page]

[image: Normal Password page]

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep initramfs
busybox-initramfs               install
initramfs-tools                 install
initramfs-tools-bin             install
initramfs-tools-core                install
```

This cure by David Lindman link posted below cured the issue. Yes, I'd set up OpenVPN during the process of getting the VPN to work:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/openvpn
```

And uncommented the line:

```
AUTOSTART="none"
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The first image shows the cryptsetup prompt for the full-disk encryption. Did you set up full disk encryption with TPM, a password, or not at all?

Comment: Not at all that I recall. Certainly not during the fix for the VPN.

Comment: What is the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep initramfs`?

Comment: Edited post to include above output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the form field »Enter Auth username« during the boot proccess mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627842/what-does-the-form-field-enter-auth-username-during-the-boot-proccess-mean)

Comment: Please don't put the answer inside the question!